# Remover botão criado dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Como um botão criado dinamicamente pode remover ele mesmo ao clicar sobre ele usando jQuery?

```
var id = 0;

function criar() {
    $("#divina").append("<button id=botao" + id +">botao</button><br>");
    id +=1;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando js puro fica mais ou menos assim:

```html
var id = 0;

function criar() { 
    $("#divina").append("<button id='botao" + id +"' onclick='remove(\"botao"+id+"\")'>botao"+id+"</button><br>");
    id +=1;
};
function remove(elementId){ 
 var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Já deu uma luz aqui e consegui usar com jQuery. Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar um atributo `onclick` chamando uma função e enviando o `this` (o `this` representa o próprio elemento, não precisa enviar o `id` do botão):

```
$("#divina").append("<button onclick='removeBotao(this)' id=botao" + id +">botao</button><br>");
                                                    ↑
```

É preciso também remover o `<br>` após o botão. Se estiver usando jQuery 1.8 pra frente, use `.addBack()` (versões anteriores a 1.8, use `.andSelf()`):

```
// até a versão 1.8
function removeBotao(e){
   $(e).next().andSelf().remove();
}

// versão 1.8+
function removeBotao(e){
   $(e).next().addBack().remove();
}
```

**Teste:**

```js
var id = 0;
function criar() {
    $("#divina").append("<button onclick='removeBotao(this)' id=botao" + id +">botao</button><br>");
    id +=1;
};

function removeBotao(e){
   $(e).next().addBack().remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divina"></div>
<button onClick="criar()">Criar</button>
```

### Com JavaScript puro

Você pode usar o método `.remove()` (não funciona no IE) ou `.outerHTML` para remover o botão e selecionar o `<br>` com `.nextElementSibling` (elemento que vem após o botão):

```js
var id = 0;

function criar() {
    $("#divina").append("<button onclick='removeBotao(this)' id=botao" + id +">botao</button><br>");
    id +=1;
};

function removeBotao(e){
   e.nextElementSibling.outerHTML = '';
   e.outerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divina"></div>
<button onClick="criar()">Criar</button>
```